# Data copy from Salesforce to Salesforce using Azure Data Factory

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

Can we use Dataflow activity in ADF for copying data from Salesforce to Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, yes, you can. Just using the proper Linked Service.

Specifically, this Salesforce connector supports:

- Salesforce Developer, Professional, Enterprise, or Unlimited editions.
- Copying data from and to Salesforce production, sandbox, and custom domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Data Flow activity does not support copying data to or from **Salesforce**.

You can refer to these Microsoft documents to check the supported datasets in **[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#supported-sources)** and **[sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#supported-sinks)** transformations in mapping data flows.

You can also raise a feature request from the ADF portal.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties) to copy data to or from Salesforce.